# Variable voltage supply (0V , 5V, 7V, 10V, 16V) rotary switch

Tags: power-supply, switch-mode-power-supply

I need to build a variable voltage supply that can generate 0V,5V,7V,10V,16V. My idea is to use a rotary switch and zener diodes. So far I got all the outputs correct with little difference from my desired output.

My question is, are the values of my resistors and capacitor correct? How can I solve for the right value of R1, R2 and C1? What (value) of the transformer do I need to buy? What do I need to change? I am just a newbie and been studying electronics for a few weeks and I need to buy these components immediately. Thanks!

[image: schem diagram]

Comment: Try reading the comments on your other question, especially the part about the 317

Comment: Hi sir, I was told by my professor not to use those components since we are just on the first stage of our electronics subject and we only need to use discrete components.

Comment: Has he told you how much current the power supply has to deliver?  Does the voltage need to be regulated?  Your schematic limits the current drastically (max of somewhere around 10 milliamperes assuming your DC voltage from the bridge is around 18V.)

Comment: Given that you are still at the very beginning, I wonder if you are supposed to be building an unregulate supply using a multitap transformer.

Comment: They wont let you use a voltage regulator in the first stages of your course, but they will let you use a 220V transformer?!?

Comment: Your circuit will subject the load to high voltage whenever the switch is operated. This comment was also made for your previous question. 

You can decide to throw away a lot of power and use a separate resistor and zener for each voltage (or stack the zeners up and use one string) but the way you are doing it is not at all good.

Comment: can someone please do the right circuit for this? I really don't have a lot of knowledge on these kind of stuff. I am reading a textbooks but I can't put it in when I am doing simulations. I need to buy the components tomorrow, and I have no time to do all of this. It would be much appreciated. PLEASE! Thank you :(

Comment: I like based it from this http://forum.allaboutcircuits.com/attachments/voltage-regulator-24v-to-3v-4-5v-6v-9v-and-12v-jpg.40208/ The voltage needs to be regulated

Comment: What parts are you allowed to use?  Do you need a regulated supply or an unregulated supply?  How much current does the power supply have to put out?  Failing answers to these questions, I will vote to close the question.  No one here will design the circuit for you, and it is damn difficult to make recommendations with no more info than you've given - especially considering the restrictions you seem to be under.

Comment: OK, that's a start.  Regulated.  Now please fill in the rest of the blanks and you might get somewhere.

Comment: He doesn't said how much current the power supply have to put out.

Comment: We need to use discrete components he said, but we should not use a potentiometer.

Comment: OK. So, your zener regulated supply might be adequate.  So, take @SpehroPefhany's comments here and in your other question to heart and make the suggested improvements.

Comment: Even better, pay attention to SpehroPefhany's comments and read Andy aka's answer.  The two should lead you to a good (enough) solution.

Comment: The schematic capture program used for the circuit above is lousy -- most of the dots on the wire junctions are impossible to see.

Answer (score 3):

> we only need to use discrete components

Then presumably you can use NPN power transistors to make the zener regulator capable of delivering more power? I guess so! Here's the general idea: -

[image]

The unregulated supply keeps the 5V6 zener "topped-up" with enough current for it to regulate at 5V6. The BJT emitter follower is so-called because the emitter *follows* what the base does (apart from the loss of about 0.6 volts). This means that if the zener is 5V6, the output is 5.0 volts. If more current is drawn by the load this fractionally increases the voltage across the B-E junction and significantly, this turns-on the BJT to *almost* counteract the loading effect of the resistor load.

It's not perfect but it overcomes the loading problem you have with zener diodes.

As an idea about this zener loading effect consider if you were trying to produce 5V with a 5V zener and you wanted to draw up to 500mA. The input supply is 12 volts and therefore the resistor R1 (14 ohms) drops 7V at +500mA (under no-load or full-load). This means that resistor is always dissipating 3.5 watts. Also the zener when off-load is dissipating 5V x 500mA = 2.5 watts.

The transistor circuit above is slightly worse at voltage regulating (compared to the zener) but, importantly, off-load it isn't throwing away power. Plus it's probably easier to get a suitable BJT in a T0-220 package than a zener. Note also that the zener and R1 in the transistor circuit only need to be low power devices - the zener voltage is being buffered by the BJT hence it only needs to be a 250mW device and the resistor probably rated no more than the same.

Many thanks to Tom Carpenter (who was also thinking along the same lines as me) but spent too much time (LOL) drawing the picture below: -

[image]

This would be the finished idea and has the benefit that you could select the zeners with common-emitter BJTs (digitally controlled) because they are only going to be consuming a few mA each.

As for the choice of transformer, this cannot be decided without knowing the full load currents you expect to deliver to your load at all the different voltage settings.

Comment: +1. I was just preparing an answer for this, but you beat me too it. In this solution you can simply use a switch to select which zener diode provides the reference to the transistor. I drew a diagram for this which you are welcome to use if you wish. (here: http://astroeq.co.uk/FileDump/ZenerReg.png). In the diagram the voltages are standard Zener diode ratings. For the 10V and 16V, you'll end up with about 9.4 and 15.4 respectively due to the transistor. Note that the highest voltage zener is never disconnected to prevent a spike when the switch is being changed.

Comment: @TomCarpenter never look a gift horse in the mouth is my motto (unless its dead of course). Nice one.

Comment: *"Note that the highest voltage Zener is never disconnected to prevent a spike when the switch is being changed"* But assuming the rotary switch temporarily breaks contact between steps, wouldn't the voltage spike to 16v between steps?  Wouldn't it  be better for the voltage to go to 0 between steps?

Comment: @tcrosley If the zener diode gets disconnected the regulator turns into a current regulator - and if the load is small this means you'll get almost the full unregulated Vin appearing at the output. By leaving one of the zeners in it ensures that the voltage is always regulated - but yes it will spike up to the highest regulated voltage.

Answer (score 1):

Here's one possible solution..

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fnj8BW.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Q1 and Q2 form a constant-current supply for the Zener-diode-LED chain that supplies the desired output voltage plus one Vbe drop at each selector switch position. Q3 is the output pass transistor. No short-circuit protection is provided.

Answer (score 0):

Your circuit would work within a very limited domain.

The Zener diodes are reverse biased using the resistor to put a current through them, this causes the relatively stable voltage (there are more stable things, but as things go, zeners are stable-ish). But if you start using a current at the output, where your measurement device is, your output voltage will drop.

For a reference sourcing a few mA this would probably work well enough, given the points made in comments and/or an apparent other question are not a problem in your design. (DO take note of them)

For an actual power supply you will need to "amplify" this signal, to make it stronger.

A better way is to have one winding on your transformer supply the 16V, then regulate that down to 10V with a 7809 and a diode, have the transformer also supply 8V, by getting one with two windings, drop that to 7V with a diode, then regulate the 8V down to 5V with a 7805 and use your rotary switch to select those supplies.

Something like this:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fvq6b8.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

NOTICE: Explanation to follow soon, I need to go into a small meeting now. Will Edit/Update. Schematic took longer with no mouse at hand than I intended.

### EDIT1:

As promised the explanation, even though a later comment stipulates the use of discrete components. The explanation of this schematic may in the end help you with your choices of transformers in your own design, or might help other users with similar questions that are not tied by a curriculum.

### Note about rectification:

First of all: I used bridge rectifiers for drawing speed and temporary clarity, but later I will show with separate diodes how the same function can be achieved with far fewer diode-barriers and in a way that is often considered neater. For now assume that each winding is rectified neatly and can be stacked like that without risk.

### Transformer Choice:

A transformer makes an AC voltage on its output. This voltage is given as an RMS voltage, this RMS voltage is a little lower than the actual maximum peak voltage in the sine-wave. As an effect of the maths used in defining this RMS voltage, the peaks will be exactly SQRT(2) times as high. This is approximately 1.41 times as high.

What happens when you rectify and smooth that RMS AC voltage, is that you take the highest peak voltage through your diodes and then take as much current as the transformer can give you to put that peak voltage into a capacitor. This capacitor will then keep that voltage for a time. This time will depend on how big the capacitor is and what the current drain is, but if you match the capacitor to your current drain, it'll be quite stable. So then the output DC voltage is almost the same as the input voltage's Peak voltage.

Now, of course in rectification the diodes do make the voltage drop a little bit, so in rectification you usually subtract 1V to 1.5V from the peak voltage to get your DC voltage, depending on the type and quality of your diodes. (Here you'll need datasheets for best accuracy.)

So, if you know the RMS AC voltage, you get the DC voltage by:

### DC(out) = (sqrt(2) * AC(rms-in)) - V(diodes)

Where V(diodes) is the voltage the diodes in the rectification uses, for full wave rectification the current always goes through two diodes, so that is twice the forward voltage of one single diode.

If you know the DC voltage you want, you get the RMS AC voltage through:

### AC(rms-in) = (DC(out) + V(diodes)) / sqrt(2)

So, for your case, we want two times 8V, to make 8V and 16V, so each winding should supply:

AC(rms-in) = (8+1.2) / sqrt(2) = 6.5VAC loaded.

In the schematic I used 2x6VAC, because those are easy to find and you might accept the slightly lower output. Else you might want to search one with 2x7V, but that'll be harder.

You can now use those formulas for whatever schematic you end up with, all you need to know is the minimum rectified DC voltage you need, if that voltage has a maximum a bit higher, always round your AC voltage up to the closest available one, to give yourself some headroom there.

The transformer current will have to be large enough to supply the loads, so in this example the top one need to be able to supply the loads for the 16V and the 10V and the bottom one will have to be able to supply the 8V and the 5V. But! Ah-hah! The bottom one will also have to work to supply the currents for the top one (verify).

Because of the rectification the current your transformer needs to be higher than your output currents added together. After all the rectifiers can't magically add energy to the power supply. Often we use VA's (volt-ampere) to overcome this on both sides and take a small margin for peak-current, but because the windings also support each other, that would actually be harder in this case. You can also remember to multiply by 1.5 and you should be pretty safe on peak-current AC side vs steady current consumption DC side.

### Capacitor Choice:

The schematic shows 2200uF, which for many adaptors would probably be sufficient, if not even on the high side. But how did I get there? Well, I'll try to explain:

As you should know, when working with AC voltages, those voltages are a sine wave. This sine wave goes between -Vpeak to +Vpeak, where the peak voltages are explained in the Transformer section.

If you want to turn that into a DC voltage, you can put it through one diode, getting rid of the negative voltage. This is called half wave rectification, because you throw away the bottom half (the negative bit) of the AC voltage. If you, in stead rectify it with four diodes, or a full bridge rectifier, you turn the negative voltage around and into another positive peak. So in half wave rectification you get a positive peak once for every wave with a gap in between the size of another half wave, and for full wave rectification you get two for every wave, leaving no gaps.

This has a big influence on your capacitor, because it needs to store enough energy to supply the load with power while the peak is gone, until the next peak comes. This time is a lot longer with half-wave rectification than with full-wave, so your capacitor will have to be at least twice as large, in practice even 2.5 times.

So, for this, I'm going to assume we use full-wave rectification, to save capacitor size.

First, for ease of calculation you assume a constant current drain, for example 0.3A. Assuming the constant current drain makes it easier, because for a voltage drop in a capacitor with a given current, you need to perform an integration over time, but if the current is constant that integration becomes a simple multiplication, because the time component is not relevant anymore (it does not change). In the assumption, you usually use your maximum current drain.

Then, you need to know the time after a peak, until a new one starts. For this you need the AC frequency. With 50Hz and full-wave the number of peaks per second after the diodes will be 100 per second (50 +Vpeak and 50 -Vpeak, both rectified to positive peaks makes 100), so the time between them is then 1/100Hz = 0.01s. This number is usually actually assumed to be 0.008 in 50Hz, for reasons I won't go into. If you use 10ms in stead of 8, you will overestimate the capacitor, so it's no big problem until you start going deeper into the theory.

The formula for the voltage drop on a capacitor in the time it is not supplied by the transformer, assuming the current is constant (this is a very important assumption) is the following:

### V(drop) = (I(drain) * t(between-tops)) / C

Or the formula for the capacitor (with the same assumption of constance) is:

### C = (I(drain) * t(between-tops)) / V(drop)

Where I is the current we assumed to be constant in ampere, t is the time between two peaks in seconds, which for 50Hz turned out to be 0.01s. V is the maximum voltage ripple or voltage drop between the peaks you are willing to tolerate in volts. In normal adaptors this is usually between 0.5V and 2V, or even 4V if they have a large margin because of a voltage regulator later. For this example I used 2V, because I don't know what would be acceptable for you. The lower the voltage you choose, the larger the capacitor will have to be.

For the example:

C = (0.3A * 0.01s) / 2V = 0.0015F = 1.5mF = 1500uF

Now because with 2V drop the 7805 will have quite a bit of trouble keeping its output stable I opted to round this up to 2200uF, which is an even more common value than 1500uF and for component simplicity I did the same for the other capacitor.

### Replacing the Bridge Rectifiers:

Now, we assumed the bridge rectifiers worked, just to keep that schematic simple without even more moaning about effects and rules and why the hells, but in general, you want to save as many diode barriers as you can, to save cost and voltage drops.

So, how could we do that more efficiently? Look at this:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fYdJyi.png)</sup>
Of course, after this you will still get the same capacitors and electronics as with the first example.

In a transformer, the current in a secondary winding is induced going one way, then the other, then back again, etc, at the frequency of the incoming current/voltage.

### So, let's see what happens in the schematic above:

If the current is induced from the bottom to the top (towards the dot), the current can flow out of the top wire and into either the middle wire or the bottom wire. So D2 will want to conduct and D1 will not, making the top output get a peak compared to the middle wire. But current can also flow out of the middle wire and into the bottom wire, conducting through D3, so the middle wire will also have a peak compare to the bottom output.

If the current flows the other direction, away from the dot, the current can flow into the top wire and out of the middle wire or out of the bottom wire. Or the current can flow out of the bottom wire and into the middle wire. This will make Diodes D4 and D1 conduct and D2 and D3 block, again making the top output have a peak compared to the middle wire and the middle wire a peak compared to the bottom output.

So this works exactly as the 2-bridge full-wave rectifier for a transformer with a middle-tap.

Comment: @PauloDelaPeña You're welcome, but it's only useful to your situation, as it turns out, now that I added some explanations on the transformer and capacitor. Andy's answer has the electronics for your case.

Comment: He can't use either the 7805 or 7809 you have in your schematic -- only discretes allowed, no ICs.

Comment: @tcrosley you might find the note just under the first schematic of interest. These comments were _all_ posted while I was widdling away at the schematic and I'm not enough of a pissant to edit my answer 2 hours later from start to finish in a bid to hijack upvotes. That's not what it is about.

Comment: @Asmyldof yep, missed the note. I read the NOTICE but not the EDIT1. Thanks for bringing it to my attention. Its a bummer when the OP adds restrictions in the middle of the game that weren't in the original question. I've had that happen to me too.  You obviously went to a lot of work writing your answer and I understand your not wanting to change it.

Comment: @tcrosley Well, it's annoying, but the answer itself is not only for the OP. I write long answers, because they also might help other people. If I explain everything and add some maths, other people with similar problems, but different values will have some use of them. Based on searches, my answer may still help others.